# How to edit a web page source and save the changes?

Tags: magento-1.9

I tried to make some changes to my `Magento` site by clicking on inspect,but I could not save the changes I made to my website. Do I have to use a web browser and a text editor such as `Notepad ++` to make changes and save them? Anyone can help on how to save the changes to my `Magento` website.

Comment: you have to download the source to your pc, make changes there, then upload the edited file.. tbh tho if you think Notepad++ is a browser then this is too difficult for you

Answer (score 0):

Some minor changes (like text edits and changing images) can be done from Magento's "admin side". To log in you need to know the admin login page url (which I always forget) as well as admin's username and password.

To make changes to your Magento's code (or HTML or CSS) you have to make the changes to Magento's code files and then upload the changed files to your server. The code files are in your server. On the other hand, this requires understanding of coding and Magento's structure. It is also warmly recommended to install Magento's development environment before doing any changes. You know, so that you can see if the changes work before you put them to Internet.

So maybe you could ask the person who made your Magento webstore if they could do the changes for you.